# Access control for method login does not work in symfony5?

Tags: symfony

I just recently started learning symfony. I can’t restrict the access of authorized users to the login method in Symfony5. It continues to work despite restrictions)) This my security.yaml:

```
security:
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: auto

providers:

    app_user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/api
        anonymous: lazy
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
                - App\Security\JwtAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
        user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
        logout:
            path: api_user_logout
            success_handler: App\Security\JwtLogoutHandler
            delete_cookies:
                jwt: { path: /, domain: / }
        stateless: false

access_control:
    - { path: '^/api/login', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Controller method:

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login", methods={"POST"})
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 */
public function login()
{

}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function logout()
{
}

/**
 * @Route("/user", name="get_user", methods={"GET"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
 */
public function getUserData()
{
    return $this->json([
        'user' => $this->getUser(),
    ],
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        [],
        [
            'groups' => ['api'],
        ]
    );
}
```

access_control works for everyone except login. @IsGranted ("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && ! IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY") also does not work for my example.
How to restrict authorized users access to login methods?

UPDATED (It would seem - Access denied, but login and logout work.):

security.yaml:

```
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: lazy
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
                - App\Security\JwtAuthenticator
            entry_point: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator
        user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
        logout:
            path: api_user_logout
            success_handler: App\Security\JwtLogoutHandler
            delete_cookies:
                jwt: { path: /, domain: / }
        stateless: true

access_control:
    -  { path: '^/', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
```

Controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login", methods={"POST"})
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_USER')", statusCode=403)
 */
public function login()
{
}

/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="logout", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function logout()
{
}
```

Comment: Never saw IsGranted configured like that.  Might need to use the Security annotation.  https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html#security  Still not sure if it will work.

Comment: Ok. Removed annotation. I could be wrong doing this for the first time. I use only security.yaml settings:
    access_control:
        -  { path: '^/', roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
It would seem - Access denied, but login and logout work. As I understand it, guard authenticator symfony intercepts a request ignoring access control.